# I would like the command to display the file disk location, and size of the recovery area?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am hoping this is a easy question to answer. Default recovery file disk location and the size set for your recovery area

Comment: Display the disk location, the size of that location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always include Oracle version and platform.

You should check v$flash_recovery_area_usage and v$recovery_file_dest

Hope that helps.